# git add multiple files at once

Tags: git, addition

I had this project with a lot .c files in source directory,then I make the project, there is  .o files inside of the project, I also want to push these files to repository,so instead of add each .o which is possible but...,how to add .o files easily?

Comment: Is it really a good idea to store object files in your repository? Seems like a strange thing to me...

Comment: Why would you possibly want to add `.o` files?

Comment: Unless you are doing something very special you definitely don't want to add any compiled files into the repository.

Comment: Just a sidenote: Check if *.o is being ignored in your `.gitignore` file. It is fairly uncommon to add .o files to the source repository. In that case you will have to force add i.e. `git add -f <files>`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Putting aside the fact, that this is just a terrible idea, you can add them as any other file:

```
git add *.o
git commit -m "Committing compiled files, which is bad"
```

Of course instead of `git add *.o` you can use `git add */*.o` or even `find -name *.o | while read x; do git add $x; done`

Comment: the reason I did this is this repository is just for me and my friend,the project took 20 minutes to compile on his computer, and I am testing if this might save a little bit of time.and this helps a lot thanks

Comment: `find -name '*.o' -type f -exec git add {} \;`

Comment: Seems like a duplicate question, Checkout this answer too, https://stackoverflow.com/a/67543452/12415637

Answer (score 75):

## How to add multiple files with *different extensions* to git all at one time...

You can add to git by explicitly listing each file with spaces as delimiters.

```
$ git add file-name-1.php file-name-2.js file-name-3.html …
```

The accepted answer is perfect for the OP’s specific case. But I got here—via Google—needing to add multiple files with *different* extensions. Posting here in case you miss this [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23621748/3965565) to a similar question.

### Don't forget about interactive staging

[Git interactive staging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging) can also work wonders. To enter interactive staging (aka: adding, removing files):

```
 $ git add -i
```

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you have ignored your `.o` file, check out your .gitignore file if it exists.
Otherwise, you can add all files just by:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "You message"
```

However, I dot think it's a good idea to trace the `.o` files. It's binary file, you'll get these files whenever you do build. Ignore it is a good practice. :)

Comment: Note that this will add all files (not just the `.o`)

Comment: @Let_Me_Be ya, I figured he may want thin one. :p