# How to add multiple files to Git at the same time

Tags: git, push, commit

This will be my first git use. I have added new files ( a lot ) to the folder/project ( git local repository).

I went through online tutorials and forums and see i can do

```
git commit -a
```

So I go to the base folder of the repository and do a

```
sudo git commit -a
```

But then, some screens comes up and asks me to add a comment which i do. i do not know how to proceed or exit. I do not want to mess up so i did ctrl + Z and did not do anything.

Can you guys please outline the commands I need to use?

```
git commit -a
```

and

```
git push?
```

Comment: `git commit -a` opens up an editor for you to type commit message. Enter a message you want to see as log and exit the editor. This completes the commit. Follow that up by pushing your changes to remote repository using `git push <remote name> <branch name>` such as `git push remote master`

Comment: also note, you don't need to (and shouldn't) use `sudo`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.If i do not use sudo i get permission denied error.

Comment: Having used sudo previously, you probably have files in your working directory that are now mistakenly owned by root. At this point doing other operations *without* sudo will cause a permission denied error because you can't change those files owned by root. Your repository might be a bit of a mess and it might be best to start over (and *don't* use sudo).

Comment: if you want to add all files you can use  ` git add -a ` .But if you want to add multiple selected files. you can use ` git add -i ' . please refer this https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging . this will help you .

Comment: This is old but I think the best way to specifically add the contents of several targeted directories is as follows: git add directory/subdirectory_1* directory/subdirectory_2*

Answer (score 156, accepted):

To add all the changes you've made:

`git add .`

To commit them:

`git commit -m "MY MESSAGE HERE"` #-m is the message flag

You can put those steps together like this:

`git commit -a -m "MY MESSAGE HERE"`

To push your committed changes from your local repository to your remote repository:

`git push origin master`

You might have to type in your username/password for github after this.  [Here's](http://alistapart.com/article/get-started-with-git) a good primer on using git.  A bit old, but it covers what's going on really well.

Comment: Will `-a` add new (unstaged) files before the commit?

Comment: `git commit -a` is shorthand for `git commit --all`, so yes, it will.

Comment: `$ man git-commit` includes this for `-a`: "Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, but new files you have not told Git about are not affected.", which is why I asked.

Comment: For completeness the easiest way to add multiple files of one type is using the asterisk, for example for html use "git add *.html"

Answer (score 569):

#### Basic Usage

Add individual files to your Git staging area using the `git add` command, followed by a list of space-separated filenames, which can include both file paths and extensions. For instance:

```bash
git add scripts/app.js images/logo.png
```

#### Advanced Usage

To streamline this process, Git offers the wildcard character asterisk `*`, which matches multiple files. For example, to add all files in your repository (excluding those in your .gitignore file):

```bash
git add *
```

For finer control, you can specify files by extension, like this:

```bash
git add *.jpg
```

Or to add all files within a specific folder:

```bash
git add images/*
```

Comment: This doesn't work when one of the file name includes a whitespace with git 1.9.5

Comment: @Reggle Pinkham Your answer would be more helpful if you also mention how to add multiple file types, cause let's not forget the case where User has 1 file of each of 2 or 3 types(extensions) to be committed. So would this `git add *.js *.vue` work ? Or will have to use comma or quotes or slash to escape the asterisk ?

Answer (score 60):

As some have mentioned a possible way is using [git interactive staging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging).
This is great when you have files with different extensions

```
$ git add -i
           staged     unstaged path
  1:    unchanged        +0/-1 TODO
  2:    unchanged        +1/-1 index.html
  3:    unchanged        +5/-1 lib/simplegit.rb

*** Commands ***
  1: status     2: update      3: revert     4: add untracked
  5: patch      6: diff        7: quit       8: help
What now>
```

If you press `2`  then `enter` you will get a list of available files to be added:

```
What now> 2
           staged     unstaged path
  1:    unchanged        +0/-1 TODO
  2:    unchanged        +1/-1 index.html
  3:    unchanged        +5/-1 lib/simplegit.rb
Update>>
```

Now you just have to insert the number of the files you want to add, so if we wanted to add `TODO` and `index.html` we would type `1,2`

```
Update>> 1,2
           staged     unstaged path
* 1:    unchanged        +0/-1 TODO
* 2:    unchanged        +1/-1 index.html
  3:    unchanged        +5/-1 lib/simplegit.rb
Update>>
```

You see the `*`  before the number? that means that the file was added.

Now imagine that you have 7 files and you want to add them all except the 7th? Sure we could type `1,2,3,4,5,6` but imagine instead of 7 we have 16, that would be quite cumbersome, the good thing we don't need to type them all because we can use ranges,by typing `1-6`

```
Update>> 1-6
           staged     unstaged path
* 1:    unchanged        +0/-1 TODO
* 2:    unchanged        +1/-1 index.html
* 3:    unchanged        +5/-1 lib/simplegit.rb
* 4:    unchanged        +5/-1 file4.html
* 5:    unchanged        +5/-1 file5.html
* 6:    unchanged        +5/-1 file6.html
  7:    unchanged        +5/-1 file7.html
Update>>
```

We can even use multiple ranges, so if we want from 1 to 3 and from 5 to 7 we type `1-3, 5-7`:

```
Update>> 1-3, 5-7
           staged     unstaged path
* 1:    unchanged        +0/-1 TODO
* 2:    unchanged        +1/-1 index.html
* 3:    unchanged        +5/-1 lib/simplegit.rb
  4:    unchanged        +5/-1 file4.html
* 5:    unchanged        +5/-1 file5.html
* 6:    unchanged        +5/-1 file6.html
* 7:    unchanged        +5/-1 file7.html
Update>>
```

We can also use this to unstage files, if we type `-number`, so if we wanted to unstage file number 1 we would type `-1`:

```
Update>> -1
           staged     unstaged path
  1:    unchanged        +0/-1 TODO
* 2:    unchanged        +1/-1 index.html
* 3:    unchanged        +5/-1 lib/simplegit.rb
  4:    unchanged        +5/-1 file4.html
* 5:    unchanged        +5/-1 file5.html
* 6:    unchanged        +5/-1 file6.html
* 7:    unchanged        +5/-1 file7.html
Update>>
```

And as you can imagine we can also unstage a range of files, so if we type `-range` all the files on that range would be unstaged. If we wanted to unstage all the files from 5 to 7 we would type `-5-7`:

```
Update>> -5-7
           staged     unstaged path
  1:    unchanged        +0/-1 TODO
* 2:    unchanged        +1/-1 index.html
* 3:    unchanged        +5/-1 lib/simplegit.rb
  4:    unchanged        +5/-1 file4.html
  5:    unchanged        +5/-1 file5.html
  6:    unchanged        +5/-1 file6.html
  7:    unchanged        +5/-1 file7.html
Update>>
```

Comment: personally i like to this way. it is easy to use when you have more files to commit and other operations.

Comment: Once you ended, how do you finish the interactive staging?

Comment: @Crparedes once you have added the files, if you press enter again it goes back to the menu, then you have to choose option `7` to quit from interactive staging.

Comment: Today I learned that there is an interactive terminal editor to stage the files..thanks @FabioAntunes

Answer (score 35):

You can also select multiple files like this

```
git add folder/subfolder/*
```

This will add all the files in the specified subfolder. Very useful when you edit a bunch of files but you just want to commit some of them...

Answer (score 16):

If you want to add multiple files in a given folder you can split them using `{,}`. This is awesome for not repeating long paths, e.g.

```
git add long/path/{file1,file2,...,filen}
```

Beware not to put spaces between the `,`.

Comment: what is long/path/ here? @EliuX

Comment: long/path could be a path string with a very long length, so its more comfortable not repeat such part, without having to `cd` into it

Answer (score 14):

Simply **use single quotations around each file name** to ensure any with spaces work as expected

```sh
git add 'file1' 'file2' 'file3'
```

Comment: Note that it can work without quotes and that directories can be combined in the list. i.e. git add file1 controllers/ file2 images/

Answer (score 6):

1. 

```
git init
```

2. 

***a) for all files***

```
git add -a
```

***b) only specific folder***

```
git add <folder1> <folder2> <etc.>
```

3. 

```
git commit -m "Your message about the commit"
```

4. 

[image]

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/yourUsername/yourRepository.git
```

5. 

```
git push -u origin master
git push origin master
```

**if you are face this error than**

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/harishkumawat2610/Qt5-with-C-plus-plus.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

**Use this command**

```
git push --force origin master
```

Answer (score 4):

When you change files or add a new ones in repository you first must stage them.

```
git add <file>
```

or if you want to stage all

```
git add .
```

By doing this you are telling to git what files you want in your next commit. Then you do:

```
git commit -m 'your message here'
```

You use

```
git push origin master
```

where origin is the remote repository branch and master is your local repository branch.

Comment: Thank you!. On the last command git push origin master. I am actually working on a different branch name ( which was created from the master branch). SO do i need to eneter my branch name or origin master. Thanks again

Comment: No problem.:) Yes, you should use your branch names, origin master are just examples.

Answer (score 4):

**To add all the changes you've made:**

```
git add .
```

**To add single folder:**

```
git add directory path
```

**To add multiple folders:**

```
git add folder1 folder2 folder3 foldern
```

**To commit all the changes:**

```
git commit -m "message"
```

**To push your committed changes from your local repository to your remote repository:**

```
git push origin branch name
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that wildcards are accepted: `git add *.py` to add all python files.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like git is launching your editor (probably `vi`) so that you can type a commit message. If you are not familiar with `vi`, it is [easy to learn the basics](https://www.google.com/search?q=vi+tutorial). Alternatives are:

- Use `git commit -a -m "my first commit message"` to specify the commit message on the command line (using this will not launch an editor)
- Set the `EDITOR` environment variable to an editor that you are familiar with

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody who replied. I successfully committed and pushed my files.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stage and commit all your files on Github do the following;

```
git add -A                                                                                
git commit -m "commit message"
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the command: `git add *CMakeLists.txt`, in order to add all the CmakeLists.txt files across the sub-directories:

> z:\Temp\proj_I2.21.09.24\CMakeLists.txt
> z:\Temp\proj_I2.21.09.24\tools\t1\src\CMakeLists.txt
> z:\Temp\proj_I2.21.09.24\tools\TAF\VV\CMakeLists.txt
> z:\Temp\proj_I2.21.09.24\tools\TAF\Executable\CMakeLists.txt
> z:\Temp\proj_I2.21.09.24\tools\TAF\Recording\CMakeLists.txt
> z:\Temp\proj_I2.21.09.24\Design\original\CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
git add file1
git commit file1
git push 
git add file2
git commit file2 --amend
git push
```

Note: git commit without -m option will open an editor for your commit message.

Answer (score -1):

git add fil1 file2 -- File names are separated with space

git add *.java  -- add file with pattern

git add . -- Add entire directory recursively

Comment: This question already has a dozen answers. Are you _entirely sure_ that this answer brings something new?

Comment: Normally people add one file at a time , even if they have to add 2 files only,(not add all).
so I have written that we can add 2 files at a time.

Comment: [The top-rated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23621748/354577) covers your first case. [The second-rated, accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19576183/354577) covers your third case. And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35181754/354577) shows wildcards.

Comment: (The _entire question_ is how to add multiple files at once. Very few answers show how to add just a single file.)